# USB device carbon copied

Tags: usb

So i was confusing myself and people who looked at the last question i posted, so i'm gonna try this again.

Say i have 2 generic brand x USB drives, both are 4gb capacity and they are called USB A and B. Can i copy the entirety of USB A into USB B, not whatever that is stored inside of USB A (that can be done i know that), but every piece of data about USB A , it's manufacturer serial number (if there is one), product ID(PID), vendor ID (VID) etc. Anything and everything that defines USB A, copied and moved to USB B, essentially making USB B a carbon copy of A other than physically being 2 separate USB drives.

Comment: Every device of the given type is going to have the same VID:PID, so it's unclear how one can use it to identify a particular piece of hardware (which is what you seem to be trying to do). And as to forging them, yes.

Comment: Very sorry about the last question, i just changed the question to something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

properties like *VID*, *PID*, *serial number*,...  are *(hard-) coded* in the *firmware* or on the *chip* of the USB device, so without being able to read out and modify the firmware of the devices  producing a carbon copy will not be possible...

there are microcontrollers with USB ports and for these firmware is accessible as open source cf i.e. the LUFA stack ( http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php , http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/files/LUFA/Doc/120730/html/_page__v_i_d_p_i_d.html )

so you can try to break into the chip of your USB device to modify its firmware ( via its programming interface i.e. JTAG, SPI,... if it not locked by fuses ) however it is questionable if it is worth the effort ...

Comment: Ah many thanks, so using these hard coded values as a parameter to authenticate a USB device to a computer is possible am i right to say so?

Comment: yes, however if you have two identical devices only their *serial numbers* differ, PID and VID are the same ...

Answer (score 0):

VID stands for Vendor ID and PID is Product ID.

Having 2 usb devices from same vendor and model will have the same PID and VID.
So using this will not make the USB device unique.

Comment: Oh there is a physical serial number of sorts too as well right?

Comment: normally no, software using hardware keys looking like usb stick is used.